# Java If-Statement in Merge Sort... Why does this work?

Tags: java, sorting, if-statement, merge

I am learning to implement some of the more simple algorithms in Java, but I can't figure out why this statement works:

```
private void doMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

    if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {
        int middle = lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2;
        doMergeSort(lowerIndex, middle);
        doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex);
        mergeParts(lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);
    }
}
```

I have gone through debug, and I don't understand how it is possible that the second instance of doMergeSort is called - doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex); - when the final iteration of the previous doMergeSort is feeding 0, 0 into the method. Wouldn't that cause the if statement to return false, and the second doMergeSort call not to execute?

This code does run, and the result is correct, but how is this possible?

Comment: Where is the confusion?  The first `doMergeSort()` will keep getting called until you hit a _base case_, which is when the lower index equals the higher index, in which case there is nothing to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the source of your confusion is it sounds like you think that the variables for `lowerIndex`, `middle` and `higherIndex` get modfied across recursive calls.  They don't.  Each recursive call gets it's own separate copy of those fields so the 2nd call to `doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex);` doesn't use updated `middle` and `higherIndex`, it uses whatever those values were when they were passed into `doMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex)`

So if were to print what the variables at each call were, they would look something like this...

```
doMergeSort(0,9)
doMergeSort(0,4)
    doMergeSort(0,2)
        doMergeSort(0,1)
            doMergeSort(0,0)
            doMergeSort(1,1)
            mergeParts(0,0,1)
        doMergeSort(2,2)
        mergeParts(0,1,2)
    doMergeSort(3,4)
        doMergeSort(3,3)
        doMergeSort(4,4)
        mergeParts(3,3,4)
    mergeParts(0,2,4)
doMergeSort(5,9)
    doMergeSort(5,7)
        doMergeSort(5,6)
            doMergeSort(5,5)
            doMergeSort(6,6)
            mergeParts(5,5,6)
        doMergeSort(7,7)
        mergeParts(5,6,7)
    doMergeSort(8,9)
        doMergeSort(8,8)
        doMergeSort(9,9)
        mergeParts(8,8,9)
    mergeParts(5,7,9)
mergeParts(0,4,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do for sequences of 0 or 1 items: they are already ordered.

So it doesn't matter (and is arguably correct) if the the function returns immediately in this cases. The behavior also forms [the base-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) - when the sequence cannot be divided further.

Answer (score 0):

I think running through an example might be best.

Let's assume the initial call is to doMergeSort(0, 3) [lowerIndex = 0, higherIndex = 3].

In this call, middleIndex will be 1 [0 + (3-0)/2]

This results in the following call:

doMergeSort(0, 1) and doMergeSort(2,3).

Looking at doMergeSort(0,1), we get the following calls:

doMergeSort(0, 0) and doMergeSort(1, 1) [lowerIndex = 0, middleIndex = 0, higherIndex = 1]

Since in both doMergeSort(0, 0) [lowerIndex = 0, higherIndex = 0] and doMergeSort(1,1) [lowerIndex = 1, higherIndex = 1], lowerIndex is not less than higherIndex, it returns right away.

Now let's look at doMergeSort(2,3) [Similar logic as above]:

It results in the call doMergeSort(2, 2) and doMergeSort(3, 3) which also returns right away due to the same reason as above [lowerIndex is not less than higherIndex]

as dkatlez pointed out, i believe your confusion comes from the fact that the variables lowerIndex and higherIndex get modified in the later recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse what happen to trivial case, when `lowerIndex` is lower than `higherIndex` by 1:

```
doMergeSort(3, 4);

private void doMergeSort(int lowerIndex = 3, int higherIndex = 4) {

    if (3 < 4) { // true
        int middle = 3 + (4 - 3) / 2; // 3.5 truncated to int -> 3
        doMergeSort(3, 3); // when you call method with lowerIndex == higherIndex
                           // first command is "if (3 < 3)" which is false and no
                           // code inside "if" is running. Your program exits from 
                           // the method and runs next command
        doMergeSort(3 + 1 = 4, 4); // same case as previous command
        mergeParts(3, 3, 4);
    }
}
```

All this happened because of two things:

1. Difference between `lowerIndex` and `higherIndex` is getting lower in every iteration;
2. Method `doMergeSort` has a boundary condition which allows to stop recursion.